# kafka docker - ERROR when sending a message

Tags: docker, terminal, zookeeper, kafka

I would like to implement kafka in a docker container. I use the official zookeper instance for kafka as docker container, too.

When I want to write a message about the terminal, on my linux mint 18.1 OS, I get the following error message.

```
foo@bar ~ $ /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:32786 --topic topic
Hello
[2017-05-16 11:01:08,245] ERROR Error when sending message to topic topic with key: null, value: 5 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for topic-0: 1532 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
```

I don't know why. Here are my docker files.

kafka config

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# see kafka.server.KafkaConfig for additional details and defaults

############################# Server Basics #############################

# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
#broker.id=${BROKER_ID}

# Switch to enable topic deletion or not, default value is false
#delete.topic.enable=true

############################# Socket Server Settings #############################

# The address the socket server listens on. It will get the value returned from 
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName() if not configured.
#   FORMAT:
#     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
#   EXAMPLE:
#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092

# Hostname and port the broker will advertise to producers and consumers. If not set, 
# it uses the value for "listeners" if configured.  Otherwise, it will use the value
# returned from java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092

# Maps listener names to security protocols, the default is for them to be the same. See the config documentation for more details
#listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL

# The number of threads handling network requests
num.network.threads=3

# The number of threads doing disk I/O
num.io.threads=8

# The send buffer (SO_SNDBUF) used by the socket server
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400

# The receive buffer (SO_RCVBUF) used by the socket server
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400

# The maximum size of a request that the socket server will accept (protection against OOM)
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600


############################# Log Basics #############################

# A comma seperated list of directories under which to store log files
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs

# The default number of log partitions per topic. More partitions allow greater
# parallelism for consumption, but this will also result in more files across
# the brokers.
num.partitions=1

# The number of threads per data directory to be used for log recovery at startup and flushing at shutdown.
# This value is recommended to be increased for installations with data dirs located in RAID array.
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

############################# Log Flush Policy #############################

# Messages are immediately written to the filesystem but by default we only fsync() to sync
# the OS cache lazily. The following configurations control the flush of data to disk.
# There are a few important trade-offs here:
#    1. Durability: Unflushed data may be lost if you are not using replication.
#    2. Latency: Very large flush intervals may lead to latency spikes when the flush does occur as there will be a lot of data to flush.
#    3. Throughput: The flush is generally the most expensive operation, and a small flush interval may lead to exceessive seeks.
# The settings below allow one to configure the flush policy to flush data after a period of time or
# every N messages (or both). This can be done globally and overridden on a per-topic basis.

# The number of messages to accept before forcing a flush of data to disk
#log.flush.interval.messages=10000

# The maximum amount of time a message can sit in a log before we force a flush
#log.flush.interval.ms=1000

############################# Log Retention Policy #############################

# The following configurations control the disposal of log segments. The policy can
# be set to delete segments after a period of time, or after a given size has accumulated.
# A segment will be deleted whenever *either* of these criteria are met. Deletion always happens
# from the end of the log.

# The minimum age of a log file to be eligible for deletion due to age
log.retention.hours=168

# A size-based retention policy for logs. Segments are pruned from the log as long as the remaining
# segments don't drop below log.retention.bytes. Functions independently of log.retention.hours.
#log.retention.bytes=1073741824

# The maximum size of a log segment file. When this size is reached a new log segment will be created.
log.segment.bytes=1073741824

# The interval at which log segments are checked to see if they can be deleted according
# to the retention policies
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

############################# Zookeeper #############################

# Zookeeper connection string (see zookeeper docs for details).
# This is a comma separated host:port pairs, each corresponding to a zk
# server. e.g. "127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:3001,127.0.0.1:3002".
# You can also append an optional chroot string to the urls to specify the
# root directory for all kafka znodes.
zookeeper.connect=${ZOOKEEPER_HOST}:2181

# Timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
```

my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:

    kafka:
        image: kafka
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 9092
        environment:
            ZOOKEEPER_HOST: zookeeper 
            KAFKA_HOST: kafka
        networks:
            u:
              aliases:
                - kafka         

    zoo1:
        image: zookeeper
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 2181:2181
        environment:
            ZOO_MY_ID: 1
            ZOO_TICK_TIME: 2000
            ZOO_INIT_LIMIT: 5
            ZOO_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
            ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888
        networks:
            u:
              aliases:
                - zookeeper
                - zoo1

    zoo2:
      image: zookeeper
      restart: always
      ports:
        - 2182:2181
      environment:
        ZOO_MY_ID: 2
        ZOO_TICK_TIME: 2000
        ZOO_INIT_LIMIT: 5
        ZOO_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
        ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888
      networks:
        u:
          aliases:
            - zookeeper
            - zoo2

    zoo3:
      image: zookeeper
      restart: always
      ports:
          - 2183:2181
      environment:
          ZOO_MY_ID: 3
          ZOO_TICK_TIME: 2000
          ZOO_INIT_LIMIT: 5
          ZOO_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
          ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888
      networks:
          u:
            aliases:
              - zookeeper 
              - zoo3

networks:
  u:
```

docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                        NAMES
00e64ae8119a        zookeeper           "/docker-entrypoin..."   20 hours ago        Up 15 minutes       2888/tcp, 3888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2183->2181/tcp   kafka_zoo3_1
1bebeb6bf4b4        zookeeper           "/docker-entrypoin..."   20 hours ago        Up 15 minutes       2888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp, 3888/tcp   kafka_zoo1_1
4385a814db83        zookeeper           "/docker-entrypoin..."   20 hours ago        Up 15 minutes       2888/tcp, 3888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2182->2181/tcp   kafka_zoo2_1
a0650d5a9c95        kafka               "/bin/sh -c /usr/l..."   20 hours ago        Up 15 minutes       0.0.0.0:32786->9092/tcp                      kafka_kafka_1
```

kafka topics

```
foo@bar ~ $ /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
test
topic
```

Comment: Is there a typo in your first code section at `lolhost:32786`? (lol)

Comment: Yes, it's a typo. I've fixed it in my post.